# How to conversionless cast an object in C without using pointers?

Tags: c

I want to cast an object in C to another type without converting the data and without need to use pointers. I know that you can do it in this manner:

```
float a = 1.2;
int b = *(int*)(&a);
```

But I would like to be able to do it to literals and structs constructed in place (if thats the right terminology for that). For example (imagine I could reference a literal for a moment):

```
void somefunc(int i){...}

somefunc(*(int*)(&1.2))
```

What I mean by constructed in place is, say I have a struct vec2:

```
struct vec2{
    float x,y;
};
```

I would like to be able to do something like

```
void somefunc(vec2 v){...}

somefunc(ConversionlessCast(vec2{1.f,2.f}))
```

Is this possible?

Edit:
I'd like to clarify that I do not care if this is safe or not. I just want to know if theres a way to do it. I should clear up that I would like to not have to make staging variables as well.

Edit2:
I realize how poorly formulated this question is without an example, and while initially typing out the example I realized what the answer to what I want to use this for is anyways.

I'm playing around with a way to do styling for a ui system I'm developing and want to be able to use one function for setting a style property. I wanted to pass a string then a value and use the string to determine how to interpret the value. It's now obvious that I should use va_args to do so. However I'm still interested in if there's a way to do what I originally asked regardless because my original plan was to use a unioned type that holds all types a property can possibly be, like

```
struct Property{
  union{
    u32 val_u32;
    f32 val_f32;
    //other possible types
  };
};
```

and then use a string that precedes this to choose which value to use. Unfortunately using an initializer list only accepts the first type, a u32. SO I wanted to come up with a way to initialize a property in a manner like

```
#define Property(x) Property{(magic that reinterprets anything as the first type on property})

Property(vec2{1.f,2.f})
```

Comment: if you want to use {}, you can use a std::initializer_list which will work for std::vector elements.

Comment: Where you got this `int b = *(float*)(&a);` from? Use `int b = (int)a;` in C.

Comment: @273K It will yield a completely different result. The OP wants to *reinterpret* the bit pattern

Comment: In general, stuff like `int b = *(float*)(&a);` is a strict aliasing violation and is UB.

Comment: Why do you tag C++ if you are asking about C?

Comment: @EugeneSh. `a` is already a float;  `*(float*)(&a)` does not do any reinterpreting

Comment: @M.M You are righ, the OP seem to confuse both me and themselves. I think they *meant* reinterpreting though. UPD: Now it is edited

Comment: I apologize, I didn't think to call it reinterpreting.

Comment: Why do you need any conversion at all? In C, you can create a `struct vec2` directly with a compound literal: `(struct vec2) { 1.f, 2.f }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reinterpret the bytes of one object as another using a union in a compound literal. In this code:

```
printf("%d\n", (union { float f; int i; }) {a} .i);
```

a union is created, and its `f` member is initialized with the value of `a`. Then the `i` member is accessed by `.i`. Per C 2018 note 99 to clause 6.5.2.3 4, that reinterprets the bytes with the new type, `int`.

(This is for C. The behavior of this is not defined by the C++ standard.)

Comment: Yes this does exactly what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Reinterpreting one type as another via pointers is a strict-aliasing violation and triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and is therefore not safe.

The safe way to do this would be to either use a union:

```
union u {
    int i;
    float f;
};
union u x = { .f=1.2f };
int y = x.i;
```

Or use `memcpy`:

```
float a = 1.2;
int b;
memcpy(&b, &a, sizeof b);
```

Comment: Or... well, just use `-fno-strict-aliasing`.

Comment: With `memcpy` one can use compound literals such as `memcpy(&b, &(float){1.2}, sizeof(b));`

Answer (score -1):

I did a little experiment - I wrote some code that *appears* to use pointers if you look at the C code, but it doesn't use pointers if you look at the generated assembly code.  Here's what I wrote:

```
static inline int float_to_int(float f) {
    return *(int*)(&f);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("%d\n", float_to_int(3.0));  // prints 1077936128
}
```

And I found this in the code the compiler generated (gcc -O2 -s):

```
main:
    ... etc ...
    movl    $1077936128, %edx
    ... etc ...
```

See that "1077936128?"  That's the final answer of the float-to-int conversion, and it's been hardwired right into the assembly code.  In other words, the program *didn't* load 3.0 into a floating point register, store the floating point number into memory, and then load it back using an integer register.  It was all done at compile time.

So question: does that count as "doing it without pointers?"  The program never actually manipulated a pointer, internally.  If that doesn't satisfy your use-case, then I need to know more about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It was only done in compile time, because `3.0` is known in compile time. Which is quite a degenerate case. It is not answering the question.

Comment: Yes this counts! Unfortunately my use case need to work for converting any type (of the same size as the type i want to convert it to, of course) into the desired type without needing to specify the type being converted from and I want to know if theres some way to do that in C in a nice succinct manner. If I were using C++ I would be using this solution, but with no overloading in C it just doesn't work.

Comment: Eugene: I know.  OP specifically asked: "I would like to be able to do it to literals."  That's the situation where he wants to be able to avoid pointers.  So, I did an experiment with literals.

Comment: For this you don't need a function. You can create a compound literal and then take an address of it: `*(int*)&(float){3.0};` : https://godbolt.org/z/q8adcenTP - and it will suffer from the same issues, such as strict-aliasing

Comment: The behavior of `*(int*)(&f)` is not defined by the C standard, and this code is completely unnecessary because there are defined ways to do it in C.

Comment: sushi: I think I understand what you're going for - you'd like to write a macro that reliably, always reinterpret-casts an object to a different type.  You can write a simple macro that works on variables,.  But the problem you're running into is that when you use your macro on a literal, the compiler complains.  I've brainstormed and brainstormed, and I just can't think of a way to write such a macro (in C).